# How to store document ID in firestore document without error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I know this question has been asked many times but mine is a little different. Im trying to store the firestore document ID inside the document itself. Whenever I try saving it, there's an error saying

_AssertionError ('package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart': Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty': a document path must be a non-empty string).

I know I'm supposed to put a space between the '' but when I do the firestore document has a blank document ID.

[image]

This is the code to create the group in firestore

```
Future<String?> addCollection(
    Username, groupName, location, postText, groupID, password) async {
  String id = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups').doc(groupID).id;
  CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups');

  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('groupID', groupID.toString());

  var result = await collection.doc(id).set({
    'groupName': groupName,
    'groupChatId': id,
    'creator': Username,
    'testmember': [],
    'location': location,
    'password': password
  });
  print(id);
  await subcollection(id: id, postText: postText, Username: Username);
  return 'Created';
}

Future<String?> subcollection(
    {id, required Username, required postText}) async {
  CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('groups');
  collection.doc(id).collection('posts').add({
    'postText': postText,
    'createdBy': Username,
    'createdAt': Timestamp.now()
  });
  return 'Created';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Im trying to store the firestore document ID inside the document itself.

Firestore has a specific method to get the auto-generated ID before the commit called doc(). Basically, you create a reference to the document with an auto-generated ID and then use it while passing your data. In your case:

```
final db = Firebase.firestore;

final newGroupRef = db.collection("groups").doc(); // Auto-Generated ID reference

final data = {
    'groupName': groupName,
    'groupChatId': newGroupRef.id, // get the id from from the refrence here 
    'creator': Username,
    'testmember': [],
    'location': location,
    'password': password
  };

newGroupRef.set(data);
```

Behind the scenes, .add(...) and .doc().set(...) are completely equivalent, so you can use whichever is more convenient.

More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document)

On a separate note, presuming you want the subCollection() to run **after** addCollection(), you should either use then() with a try catch or use [Transactions/Batch writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) because the last thing you want you is for your subCollection() to run before addCollection().